# If an ASP.NET application uses many DLLs, what's the best approach for keeping configurations of each dll separate?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

After creating settings for each `dll`, a `.dll.config` file is generated. If that `dll` be part of an asp.net application, how to keep this configurations separate for each `dll` and don't merge them into `web.config` ?

Example:
I have a GMailSender class library (DLL) which sends email via GMail servers. All you need is an instance of GMailSender, like this:

```
GMailSender gms = new GMailSender();
gms.To = "myfriend@yahoo.com";
gms.Subject = "System.Configuration dilemma";
gms.Body = "Can anyone help me with this question ?";
gms.Send();
```

Consider `GMailSender` is inside `GMailSender.dll` and it's configuration file is `GMailSender.dll.config` and the username and password of GMail account are inside it.

I want this `DLL` use the config file of itself (both dll and config in the same directory, i.e in `Bin` folder of an ASP.NET application) or beside a desktop application. This way the GMailSender is independent of who is using him for retrieving it's configurations (current `AppDomain` who has loaded this `DLL`).

I want this without reconstructing the wheel (no custom configuration classes). I guess its possible with `System.Configuration` but this namespace is probably the worst designed of .NET !

Please don't tell why you designed so that ...

This is a `plug-in` based design and finally `MEF` do some kind of it now in .NET 4.0, but there's the same problem for `Parts` configurations. With `MEF` at least I don't need anymore to argue for `plugin-based` design advantages.

Comment: Answer to this question is the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4078563/mef-parts-configuration-where-to-store too. I used to design my projects the way recently MEF do in .NET 4.0. Now the same problem is with configuration for parts which is gonna be solved in next decade !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need can be achieved using **Custom Configuration Sections**. This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) provides some details and samples on how to implement such config sections.

If you need simple **key/value** configs, like in the appSettings section, then creating a custom configuration section is quite simple.

The first thing you need to do is define your **config section** inside web.config:

```
<configSections>
  <section name="GmailSettings" restartOnExternalChanges="true" type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler" />
</configSections>
```

Now inside the web.config file you can **declare** the GmailSettings section and set the location of the external config file that you are going to use for that setting:

```
<GmailSettings configSource="GmailSettings.config"></GmailSettings>
```

**configSource** specifies the name and location of the external config file used for defining the GmailSettings section. Please note the `restartOnExternalChanges` attribute used when defining the section. Set it to true if you want the application to be automatically restarted when you modify the GmailSettings.config file (as it does when you modify the web.config file).

Below is an example of how to implement the **GmailSettings.config** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<GmailSettings>
  <add key="userName" value="blabla"/>
  <add key="password" value="moreBla"/>
</GmailSettings>
```

You can access the settings from GmailSettings using the `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()` method or by implementing a **helper class** like the one below:

```
public class GmailSettings
{
    private static readonly GmailSettings _instance = new GmailSettings();
    private NameValueCollection _settings = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("GmailSettings") as NameValueCollection;

    public static GmailSettings Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    public string this[string key]
    {
        get { return _settings[key]; }
    }
}
```

The settings can now be accessed like `GmailSettings.Instance["userName"]`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is most complete answer. Unfortunately you answered after the bounty was granted and it seems I cannot cancel it now.

Comment: @Xaqron, I noticed your question since yesterday but it was only now that I got the time to answer it. I saw that the bounty was already awarded, but I found the question interesting and decided to answer it anyway. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Creating an App.config for a DLL is not a good practice. Configuration belongs to the running application. The class library dll is supposed only to provide services to the calling application.

## HOWEVER

If you wrote the DLLs on your own, then you can make these DLL's code prefer their own independent .dll.config file rather than the global App.config/Web.config (in your ASP.NET case) using a trick.

[This method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224437(v=VS.80).aspx) allows you to open any executable file's .config file, but no one prevents you from calling it with "Mydll.dll" as argument, and has the same effect. But this works only if you can access these DLL's code.

A good practice is to use configuration sections, which are easy to maintain when merged inside a single configuration file.

Comment: I've tried that. It doesn't work with asp.net since dlls are not executing from bin folder, instead asp.net would run a copy from a temp folder which it's address changes on every application restart. I wonder why dll.config is not popular when a dll have configurations which are not related to the using application. Consider a mailSender which stores the username/password of using account in it's dll.config

Comment: There can be a workaround to it. I don't currently remember exactly which methods can help you, but you can copy any file you want from any directory to the directory ASP.NET is executing. Try to search how to get the path ASP.NET copied the compiled web application in Temporary ASP.NET folder and there copy the .config files.

Answer (score 1):

To do what I believe you want to do -- give your DLL a configuration file about which referencing assemblies need no nothing, you can[1] do something like the following code.

```
static class DllConfigurationFactory
{
    public static Configuration GetConfigurationInstance()
    {
        string           callingAssemblyPath = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location ;
        string           configFilePath      = string.Concat( callingAssemblyPath , ".config" ) ;

        // getAttributes hurls with a multitude of exceptions
        FileAttributes   attributes  = File.GetAttributes( configFilePath ) ;
        bool             isDirectory = ( (attributes&FileAttributes.Directory) == FileAttributes.Directory ? true : false ) ;
        if ( isDirectory )
        {
            throw new FileNotFoundException() ;
        }

        // check for (and die with an SecurityException) if we dont' have read access
        new FileIOPermission( FileIOPermissionAccess.Read , configFilePath ).Demand() ;

        ExeConfigurationFileMap configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configMap.ExeConfigFilename = configFilePath ;
        Configuration instance = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        return instance ;
    }

}
```

This factory method does the following:

1. Finds the fully-qualified path of the assembly of the caller ((not that of the assembly containing the factory -- it, after all, might be in its own DLL).
2. Tacks a ".config" on to the end of that path (thus yielding something like 'C:\usr/bin/local/foo/myAssembly.dll.config'.
3. Ensures that that file exists and is readable, throwing an appropriate exception if not.
4. Using that path as the source, instantiates a new instance of System.Configuration.Configuration and returns it to the caller.

**Notes**

- Visual Studio will take an app.config in your DLL project and turn it into a foo.dll.config file, **but** your build/deploy/install system is responsible for copying it to the correct location(s). Visual Studio will put it in the bin directory for the DLL project, but it won't get copied any further up the line.
- You may need to do some experimenting -- you might need to include appropriate entries in the  element, even for "standard" sections, since you're outside the normal config file hierarchy. I'm not sure on this, though. In my test, it found and loaded the  element without a  element defined, so you might have full access to the user and machine config files as well, but I don't make any guarantees about that. YMMV and all that.

Good Luck!

[1] TMTOWTDI as they say in Perl (There's more than one way to do it). You could also, for instance, create a custom section and park it in machine.config.

And there's no requirement that you use the .Net configuration system for this: your factory method could slurp in any arbitrary XML and deserialize it into an object of your choice. This would give you a strongly typed, bound access to the configuration properties, albeit at the expense of automatic refreshing when the config file gets changed. Although...you could also just put a wrapper around the standard Configuration object that would provide the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for cannot be done out of the box. Also, ASP.NET do a shadow copy on DLLs so writing a custom configuration class is not easy to. Your DLLs are not run from Bin folder. THey run from `appDomainSetup.CachePath` so the *.dll.config files are not beside their assemblies at run-time.

You can add a refrence to *.dll.config files inside web.config instead of copy/paste all key/values from DLL configuration files into web.config; This is possible by using `File` element in web.config.

I think this is not intended by designers in past and composition became popular in recent years.

Answer (score 0):

I would add configuration settings to the web.config file and call:

ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllName.MySetting"]

This means all configuration settings are in one place and not in the Bin folder.

Comment: I'm looking for the opposite of your solution. I need each *.dll.config separate and not to merge all of them into web.config; Overall concept is, desperating plugins configurations from host applications.

Comment: @Xaqron: ok...Another idea could be to create an xml file in the bin folder (DllName.xml) to store configuration, a generic XML Serialization/Deserialization class could be created to map the reading/writing of this xml file.