# MEF parts configuration, where to store?

Tags: asp.net, configuration, .net-4.0, mef

In `ASP.NET`, `.NET 4.0`, `MEF`, I put all parts in a folder and importing them using `DirectoryCatalog`. Everything is fine. Some of part have related configurations. I don't want put them in `web.config`. Maybe a good approach be a `config` file just beside the part with a `.config` added to the end.

**What is the best way for storing part configuration ?**

Answer (score 3):

I was able to create a separate config file for each DLL and successfully was able to read the keys. But when I tried to create a custom config section, I was not able to read from the DLL's app config. It always wanted to read from the MEF Consumer exe.

Here is the code to read from the consumed dll's own app config

```
var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); 
    return appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["SomeKeyName"].Value;
```

Since I was not able to read from a custom config section, I ended up using xml and serializing the custom configuration section to an object. Since you are just getting the mail server info you will have no problem using app.config.

Comment: What I forget to say is, it's an asp.net project. As I know assemblies are not run from bin folder, instead a copy of them would be executed from a temp folder.